# Internal navigation rejected for iframe: <allow-navigation> not set in Cordova iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

We load a mobile website into our Cordova app, while on the website are some iframes (eg content for tracking or support from external partners).

The idea was to whitelist only our websites host for navigating inside the Cordova Container/WebView. But on Cordova iOS this is rejecting all iframes on the page, in the logs the message appears:

`"Internal navigation rejected: <allow-navigation> not set".`

(How) Is it possible to whitelist only our host for navigating inside the app but giving a wildcard for iframes, eg `https://*` ?

Comment: use plugin cordova-plugin-inappbrowser , It's fast and better than iframe Tag .

Comment: Problem is, there are editors and frontend designers which like to add or delete iframes on demand via CMS without the need of releasing a new cordova app build for every change.